# what bits of info are stored in pinterest image urls?

Tags: image, node.js, pinterest

The first bit before the _ is the id of the pin...what are the *ZZtfjmGQ* used for? I'm assuming the _c is probalby something to do with size.

```
http://media-cache-lt0.pinterest.com/upload/33284484717557666_HZtfjmFQ_c.jpg
```

I'm building an image upload service in node.js and was curious what other sites do to store the image.

Comment: I have built something similar and while this is purely conjecture, I assume the hash after the ID bit is to give the image version a UID in a CDN (the use of a subdomain leads me to believe their images are hosted on a CDN). Without the UID, the CDN would cache the image and any changes to the image wouldn't matriculate until the TTL expires.

Comment: Didn't think of that, you're probably right. Sounds like something I don't need to worry about until I have a cdn.

Comment: In the interest of exploration, any idea about the bit after the last underscore? Image size maybe?

Comment: That is image size. When you upload, they create _t  (thumb), _b, and _c. _c is the large size.

Comment: I"m curious how they generate these images, after initial upload, there is no _t, _b, or _c image yet. and it's not served off cdn. At somepoint these other sizes get generated and are served from cdn.

Comment: See my answer below... mostly because I want my repz and it'll give you a jumping off point =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final images are served from a CDN, evident by the subdomain in the URL. The first bit, as you pointed out, is the id of the image, the second bit is a UID to get around cache limitations for image versions, and the last bit is image size.

A limitation of CDNs is the inability to process the image after upload. To get around this, my service uploads the files to my Nodejs server where I then serve the image back to the client. I use a jQuery script the user can use to crop the image which sends crop coordinates back to the server and I use ImageMagick to create the various sizes of the the uploaded image. You can obviously eliminate the crop step and just use aspect ratio's to automatically create the needed image sizes. I then upload the final images to the CDN for hosting to end users.

When a user needs to update a photo already in the CDN, the user uploads to nodejs server, images are processed and sized, the UID hash is updated and then uploaded to the CDN. If you want to keep things clean (and cut on CDN cost) you can delete the old "version" at this step as well. However, in my service I give the option to backtrack to an older version if needed.

The rest of the CRUD actions are pretty self explanatory. You can read a list of images available from the CDN using the ID (My service has a user id as well as an image id to allow more robust query operations) and deleting is as simple as identifying the image you want to delete.